# c# function inside while won't cycle

Tags: c#, while-loop

hi everybody i have this code

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\lorenzov\\Desktop\\gi_pulito_neg.txt");
string line = reader.ReadLine();
string app = "";
int i = 0;

while (line != null)
{
   i++;
   line = reader.ReadLine();
   if (line != null)
   {
       int lunghezza = line.Length;
   }

   Console.WriteLine(i);
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
   string ris= traduttore.traduci(targetLanguage, line);

   // Console.WriteLine(line);
   // Console.WriteLine(ris);
   // Console.Read();
   // app = app + ris;

   // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

   File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\lorenzov\Desktop\gi_tradotto_neg.txt", ris + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

the fact is that i have a txt file which i want to translate with this function traduci(targetLanguage,line), the function is ok, i want to translate each line into another file, while is looping the function is blocking at the first loop, if i insert consonle.read() when i press enter the function works...ho can i do? thank you all!

Comment: what happens if you use debug mode?

Comment: i'm in debug mode, i'm wondering if it's maybe because the function returns a string and this breaks the loop...

Comment: if you skip your while on the first pass then line is most likely null. Also: keep in mind that with your current code you skip the first line in your file.

Comment: Where is the second loop?

Comment: really my fault!!! ahah i left a console.read() on the other function traduci... thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty messy. I would suggest the following method to loop over the StreamReader lines:

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\lorenzov\\Desktop\\gi_pulito_neg.txt"))
        {
            string line;

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();

                // ... process the line
            }
        }
```

Comment: even better to do it this way!

Answer (score 0):

If ReadLine returns a null, your code will break. better structure:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\lorenzov\\Desktop\\gi_pulito_neg.txt");
string line;
string app = "";
int i = 0;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   i++;
   int lunghezza = line.Length;

   Console.WriteLine(i);
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
   string ris= traduttore.traduci(targetLanguage, line);

   // Console.WriteLine(line);
   // Console.WriteLine(ris);
   // Console.Read();
   // app = app + ris;

   // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

   File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\lorenzov\Desktop\gi_tradotto_neg.txt", ris + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as it stands will skip over the first line, as you use `ReadLine()` twice prior to fist use.

You can restructure the code as

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\lorenzov\Desktop\gi_pulito_neg.txt"))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\lorenzov\Desktop\gi_tradotto_neg.txt"))
{

    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
       string ris = traduttore.traduci(targetLanguage, line);

       writer.WriteLine(ris);

       line = reader.ReadLine();
    }

}
```